# How to run JavaScript when specific part of page is loaded when AJAX is involved?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, load

I am working on a page where elements are loaded via AJAX, it is a CMS type software and **I have no access to the ajax**, nor do I know it's callbacks.

I want to run my function when a specific part of the page is loaded, how can I do this when AJAX is involved?

My JavaScript, which works fine by itself: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ow0sq4su/2/):

```
var personalitet = document.getElementById("personalitet").innerHTML;
document.getElementsByName("form[5553]")[0].value = personalitet;
```

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("personalitet").onload = function() {

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

window.onload = function(){
```

None of which work, as the elements are not loaded at the time my script looks for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mutation observer.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++) {
        // PUT ACTIONS HERE
        console.log(mutations[i].type);
    }   
});

var observeElements = {
    attributes: true, 
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true 
};

observer.observe(document.body, observeElements);
```

This will let you know when anything in the body has changed. Read more about the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) if you wanna get fancy.

It's not quick, though, and you should investigate if you could abuse your CMS to not get in your way.
And it needs to call the last line before any mutations occur or it won't work.

Comment: Please make a note that this is very slow and will have performance impact

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for, I can however not figure out how to run the script. https://jsfiddle.net/ow0sq4su/3/ - I have updated my fiddle here, have I made some mistake? It doesn't seem to work in the fiddle, nor on the page. Thank you very much for your time and suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in my code (now corrected). Replace your for() statement with `for (var i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++) {`

Comment: of course, this code has to be loaded as early as possible

Comment: Thanks guys, I've added your clarifications to my post.

Comment: Hah, it ain't pretty with all the uncaught TypeErrors, but god without any access to the code or ajax callback, I'm amazed that it works, thanks so much for the help, I am marking yours as the answer.